# Why AddAfter() has constant time?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

In linked list operations, Addbefore(node,key) has linear time i.e., O(n) but AddAfter(node,key) has constant time i.e., O(1). Can anyone tell the reason?

Comment: This is only true for singly linked lists. Think about how they are chained.

Comment: It depends on your implementation... May you post how it is organized/implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture how a singly-linked list is organized:

```
A->B->C->D
```

Now, imagine you want to add a node after B. You can directly access the node and access its `next` pointer to link in a new node. So if you create a new node, call it X, with the passed key, you can do this:

```
Copy B's next pointer to X  // B and X both point to C
Set B's next pointer to X   // B points to X and X points to C

AddAfter(node,key)
{
    newNode = CreateNewNode(key);
    newNode.next = node.next;
    node.next = newNode;
}
```

But if you want to add before, you don't know which node comes *before* B. So you have to scan the list to find out:

```
AddBefore(node, key)
{
    parent = head;
    // find the node that points to the passed node
    while (parent.next != node)
    {
        parent = parent.next;
    }
    // Then add the new node after parent
    AddAfter(parent, key);
}
```

That's not necessary with a doubly-linked list, because each node has a pointer to its predecessor as well as to its successor.

Jim

Comment: yes it was for singly linked list. and thanks jim. it was really helpful

Comment: The second scan can be avoided by having an extra pointer right ? in both cases, we have to first search to find the matching element before doing after/before inserting operation. So the complexity shouldn't be constant for one and linear for another one. Both have linear time complexity.